# jquery .find() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code should clear the checkboxes when I click the button. It works if I remove the `<form></form>`  tags, but I thought `.find()` was supposed to find all descendants?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

      var clearCheckboxes = function() {    
        $('.outerbox').find('input').each(function() {
          $(this).attr('checked', false);
        });
      }

      $('input.myButton').click(clearCheckboxes);
});
</script>

<div class="outerbox">    
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" /> checkbox1
    <input type="checkbox" checked="" /> checkbox2
  </form>    
</div>
<input class="myButton" value="clear checkboxes now" type="button"/>
```

Comment: Try using .prop instead of .attr

Comment: It's working fine apparently - http://jsfiddle.net/gYHKA/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/CgsEu/

Comment: I meant, prop still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any js error on the page?

Comment: This jsFiddle has your code in it and it seems to work fine. Doesn't seem to be a jQuery issue, maybe the browser you are using. http://jsfiddle.net/aC6g2/

Comment: The links you guys posted do work on my browser, but it doesn't work when I put it into my app or on the TryItEditor for w3 schools

Comment: (Stupid question) Do you have jQuery loaded on your page?

Comment: yes :) would be a good question though. Actually, does it have anything to do with the fact that I'm trying to call this code on .submit rather than .click?

Comment: @user1199713: The `<form>` submission may be happening before your code executes.  If you show us your *real* code we can help you out.  You might just need to add `e.preventDefault()` to your handler to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/CgsEu/

Anyway, if you are using the latest jQuery, try changing `.attr` to `.prop`.  Also the `.each` isn't needed.  `.attr` and `.prop` work on all elements in a jQuery object.

```
var clearCheckboxes = function() {    
    $('.outerbox').find('input').prop('checked', false)
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CgsEu/1/

If there are other inputs, try limiting the `.find` to just checkboxes.

```
var clearCheckboxes = function() {    
    $('.outerbox').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false)
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CgsEu/2/

Comment: This works and is much neater, thanks!  I think it didn't work because I was trying to submit a form at the same time :/

Comment: Although on second thoughts that doesn't explain why it worked when the checkboxes were children (1 level down), but stopped working whenever I added any inbetween layer..... any ideas would be most welcome, but if not, oh well!

Comment: @user1199713: The `<form>` submission may be happening before your code executes.  If you show us your *real* code we can help you out.  You might just need to add `e.preventDefault()` to your handler to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use each(), you already have a collection of the elements and can apply the change to all of them, like so:

```
var clearCheckboxes = function() {    
    $('input', '.outerbox').attr('checked', false);
}

$('input.myButton').click(clearCheckboxes);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/SVBHP/1/)

There are a lot of suggestions to use prop() over attr(), and that is probably sound advice.

> According to the W3C forms specification, the checked attribute is a
>   boolean attribute, which means the corresponding property is true if
>   the attribute is present at all—even if, for example, the attribute
>   has no value or an empty string value. The preferred
>   cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is
>   to check for a "truthy" value on the element's property using one of
>   the following:
>
> if ( elem.checked )
>
> if ( $(elem).prop("checked") )
>
> if ( $(elem).is(":checked") )
>
> To maintain backwards compatability, the .attr() method in
>   jQuery 1.6.1+ will retrieve and update the property for you so no code
>   for boolean attributes is required to be changed to .prop().
>   Nevertheless, the preferred way to retrieve a checked value is prop().

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clearCheckboxes = function() {    
      $('.outerbox').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
      });
  }

  $('input.myButton').click(clearCheckboxes);
});​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/swTkx/)

**Update:**

```
$('.outerbox').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
```

or

```
$('.outerbox input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/swTkx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use prop, e.g.

```
$(this).prop('checked', false);
```

instead if `attr`

Answer (score 0):

```
var clearCheckboxes = function() {    
  $('input[type="checkbox"]', '.outerbox').prop('checked', false);
}

$('input.myButton').click(clearCheckboxes);
```